# Silverlight zoom in Out of Browser

Tags: silverlight, out-of-browser

Is it possible to use Zoom functionality of whole Silverlight application (CTRL+MouseWheel / zoom in browser) in Out of Browser mode?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following in your *Application_Startup*:

```
RootVisual = new WebBrowser() {Source = new Uri(Current.Host.Source, "../")};
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. I have implemented this code for "Zoom In" and "Zoom Out" Button Click.

In Button Click Event :

```
commonwidth = commonwidth + (commonwidth * zoomPercent / 100) //For Zoom Out
commonwidth = commonwidth + (commonwidth * zoomPercent / 100) //For Zoom In
```

Then Call this Method :

```
            Private Sub ChangZoom()

            If Not fresult Is Nothing Then

                If fresult.Count() > 0 Then

                    Dim mainFrame As StackPanel

                    mainFrame = fresult(_currentPage)

                    Dim docBorder As Border

                    docBorder = mainFrame.Children(1)

                    Dim docImage As FrameworkElement

                    docImage = docBorder.Child

                    If Not docImage Is Nothing Then

                        Dim actualWidth As Double
                        Dim actualHeight As Double

                        actualWidth = commonwidth 'Me.ActualWidth - 30
                        actualHeight = Me.ActualHeight

                        Dim newHeight As Double

                        newHeight = actualWidth * docImage.Height / docImage.Width

                        docImage.Width = actualWidth
                        docImage.Height = newHeight

                        RenderResutlFrame(_currentPage)

                    End If

                End If

            End If

        End Sub

        Public Property ImageUrl As String Implements IDocumentViewer.ImageUrl
            Get
                Return _imageUrl
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _imageUrl = value

                'Me.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(AddressOf OnInitialized)

            End Set
        End Property
```